# Decent but simple authentication for Web REST API

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication

Let's say I have some Web API and I want it to use only the users who know the password. And I have a URL like this:

```
GET http://api.example.com/v1/dog/123
```

I don't need to much security here. So, it is secure enough to just supply a password like this:

```
GET http://api.example.com/v1/dog/123?password=myPassword
```

Of course, it's a plain text and a GET request which is not secure at all. But I can't use https for now (if it would help).

What are the other option for decent but not complicated authentication?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that an explicit user login would be in order.  Once the user is authenticated, authentication cookies in the GET request allow access the resource.

If you web service is in Java, the J2EE container takes care of all this for you.  See the following tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html.  To sum this up, the application server provide protection on a per-resource basis.  The server also allows you to chose from multiple methods of authentication (form, basic, ...).

Comment: but how can a desktop applicaion use cookie?

Comment: This is a standard approach for authentication.  If the desktop application is a web client (like a browser or a REST client application), then upon attempting to access a remote, protected URI/resource, the client will be required to login.  Upon successful login, the server will respond with cookies, one of which corresponds to the user's session (JSESSIONID for a Java server)....

Comment: The client, in turn, will include this cookie in subsequent requests to the server.  The server will then read this cookie and recognize that it represents an authenticated user, thus providing access to the resource.

Comment: The browser comment was just for reference.  The behavior of any web client will be similar to a browser (e.g. request/response, include cookies from domain in subsequent requests...)

Comment: I see. What data should a cookie contain? It can't contain just isAuth=true because it's insecure.

Comment: If you use a Java application server (see tutorial above), you do not have to construct the cookie.  That is provided by the application server.  I am sure non-Java servers provide the same.  And yes it is secure enough, at least over SSL.

Comment: I don't use Java. I want to do it myself.

Comment: If I generate some "session key" to pass it via cookie, what would be the difference between that action and passing a password itself in a header? That is, I have to pass something with each request: either a password or a cookie.

Comment: The differences are (1) The application server creates the cookie for you, and most HTTP client APIs will take care of including the cookie in subsequent request to the same domain.  Bottom line - most all of the work is done for you.  You do not have to write client or server code to take advantage of this.   (2) The session key is encrypted.  This is more secure than passing a password in a header.  And it is simpler/more-secure than passing an encrypted key as encryption details are confined to the server.

Comment: As I said before, both of my applications, server and client, are built myself, therefore I have to take cafe of sending and receiving a key or a cookie by writing code. There is no built-in functionality such as: encrypting a cookie, creating a cookie for me, etc. That is to say, I don't see any difference between sending a cookie or a password.